# System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object in System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode

Tags: mono, xamarin, monomac, xamarin.mac

In Xamarin.Mac i get the next exception:

```
Unhandled Exception:
    System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
      at System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder.GetCustomEncoderFromConfig () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at System.Lazy`1[System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder].InitValue () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
      at System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder.GetCustomEncoderFromConfig () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at System.Lazy`1[System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder].InitValue () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

When i try to use the static method: `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(string);`, and only if the Mono Runtime is included in the bundle, when is not included, works perfect. Any idea of what is happening?

Comment: seems to be a mono bug, report it in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be solved, adding this line of code before the call of the method: `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(string);`

```
HttpEncoder.Current = HttpEncoder.Default;
```

The original answare can be found here: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/4805/system-nullreferenceexception-with-system-web-httputility-htmldecode#latest

And the report of the bug with a more complete explanation, can be found here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=12565